# Problem in upgrade from 14.04 to 16.04.1

Tags: apt, 16.04, upgrade

I wanted to upgrade my system. So I did a :

```
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

But I have this major error :

```
Upgrading Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-qgoff5d4/xenial", line 8, in 
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-qgoff5d4/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeMain.py", line 242, in main
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-qgoff5d4/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeController.py", line 1876, in run
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-qgoff5d4/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeController.py", line 1841, in fullUpgrade
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-qgoff5d4/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeController.py", line 1257, in doDistUpgrade
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'e' referenced before assignment
Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 109, in apport_excepthook
    pr.add_proc_info(extraenv=['PYTHONPATH', 'PYTHONHOME'])
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/report.py", line 532, in add_proc_info
    self['ExecutableTimestamp'] = str(int(os.stat(self['ExecutablePath']).st_mtime))
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-qgoff5d4/xenial'
```

Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-qgoff5d4/xenial", line 8, in 
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-qgoff5d4/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeMain.py", line 242, in main
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-qgoff5d4/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeController.py", line 1876, in run
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-qgoff5d4/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeController.py", line 1841, in fullUpgrade
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-qgoff5d4/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeController.py", line 1257, in doDistUpgrade
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'e' referenced before assignment

I looked for everywhere but I can't find a solution. If somebody can help, it would be grateful.

Answer (score 3):

You can try *sudo apt install -f* but otherwise it's preferable to do a clean install.
Online upgrades may not work with proprietary graphics drivers installed and active.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

First: You need to update the system.

Open a terminal,

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

Run it:

```
exec sudo -i
apt-get update
apt-get dist-upgrade
apt-get autoremove
apt-get clean
```

Reboot your system to finish installing updates, and to change upstart to systemd:

Open a terminal,

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

Run it:

```
exec sudo -i
add-apt-repository ppa:pitti/systemd
apt-get update
apt-get install systemd libpam-systemd systemd-ui
apt-get dist-upgrade
cp /etc/default/grub /etc/default/grub.bak
nano /etc/default/grub
```

In the open file leave this line so:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT = "init=/lib/systemd/systemd"
```

Continue running:

```
update-grub
ln -fs /proc/self/mounts /etc/mtab
```

Reboot your system,

With any problems, to undo changes run:

```
exec sudo -i
mv /etc/default/grub.bak /etc/default/grub
update-grub
```

If everything goes fine, and to upgrade to new available version:

Open a terminal,

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

Run it:

```
exec sudo -i
update-manager -d
```

Software Updater will show up and search for the new release, after a few seconds, you will see a screen like below that saying:

However, Ubuntu 16.04 is available now.

Press the button Upgrade to start upgrading to Ubuntu 16.04.

The Software Updater will ask you to confirm still you want to upgrade, press Start Upgrade to begin installing Ubuntu 16.04.

Now, the Software Updater will prepare to start setting up new software channels, and after a few minutes, the software updater will notify you the details the number of packages are going to be removed, and number of packages are going to be installed, press Start upgrade to continue.

Ended the dist-upgrade, reboot your system and:

Open a terminal,

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

Run it:

```
exec sudo -i
dpkg --configure -a
apt-get -f install
apt-get update
apt-get dist-upgrade
apt-get autoremove
apt-get clean
```